# How to create an empty file in a scratch container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

How to create an empty file in a scratch container in a Dockerfile?

#### Try 1

Obviously, `touch` is not available:

```
FROM scratch
RUN ["touch", ".emptyfile"]
```

Result:

```
container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"touch\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

---

#### Try 2

Unfortunately, `/dev/null` is not available either:

```
FROM scratch
COPY /dev/null .emptyfile
```

Result:

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder872453691/dev/null: no such file or directory
```

---

I could create an empty file in the Docker host build context and then `COPY` it, but you know, that would be too easy.

Any ideas?

Comment: you cant because there is no /bin/bash in the scratch image, https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/17896

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are no commands in scratch to run. The only options you have from scratch are `COPY` and `ADD`. And you can only copy or add files from the context (unless you want to `ADD` from a remote url which I wouldn't recommend). So you are left to create an empty file in your context and copy that.

And then docker introduced multi stage builds, which let's you use another build as your context. So you can make an empty file in one stage and copy it to the other.

```
FROM busybox AS build-env
RUN touch /empty

FROM scratch
COPY --from=build-env /empty /.emptyfile
```

Comment: To create the empty file, simply run `touch empty` in the same folder as your Dockerfile.

Comment: That's excluded by the OPs question.

Comment: Except for the bit where he states "Obviously, touch is not available"

Comment: They asked to do it "in a Dockerfile", acknowledging they "could create an empty file in the Docker host build context and then COPY it" if they wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt didn't work because Docker's `COPY` command works a bit differently than `cp` does. Instead of working the way `cp /dev/null` does in bash, `COPY` takes `/dev/null` literally and actually tries (and fails) to find a local file named `/dev/null`.

Your first attempt didn't work because the scratch image is completely, absolutely empty. The scratch container doesn't contain the executable that runs the `touch` command, in fact there's not even any Unix installation to even recognize the `touch` command. Not only can you not run `touch` (which you seem to have known already), but you can't even run *anything* in a scratch container unless it's an executable that you put in the container yourself when you built it.

Since there's nothing you can do within the container, the only way you can add anything to the container is using `COPY` or `ADD` in the Dockerfile.